# Git commit template in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I have added into global git config

```
git config --global commit.template ~/.gitmessage
```

Created the `~/.gitmessage` file:

```
 [one line-summary of changes]

Because:
- [relevant context]
- [why you decided to change things]
- [reason you're doing it now]

This commit:
- [does X]
- [does Y]
- [does Z]
```

If I use `git commit` without parameter `-m` the template is loaded in terminal

How do I make Xcode to load the template?

REF: [Source](https://medium.com/@alex.wasik/create-a-custom-git-commit-template-84468232a459)