# Can I autofill Xcode's commit message with some template?

Tags: xcode, git, github, commit, xcode11

I'm unsure whether or not this is possible to do, but if it is it'll make things a lot easier for me.

Can I automatically fill the following box in Xcode's `Source Control > Commit` with some template?

[image: Xcode's commit message box.]

Ideally, I would like it to autofill with some plaintext template like this:

```
(Brief description)

(More detailed description if necessary)

Fixed issues:
New issues:
```

As this is different to automatically incrementing a build number, for example, I'm not sure if this is even possible to do. If it isn't, please inform me that this can't be done.

I am currently in Xcode 11.4 but will be updating to 11.6 soon.

Comment: Related (maybe dupe): [Git commit template in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58048034/2602718)

Comment: @scohe001Thanks, but I'm not doing this from terminal.

Comment: Neither is the OP of that other question. Their question ends with "*How do I make Xcode to load the template?*" which is--I presume--the same thing you're trying to do (that is, make git templates that work on the command line work in Xcode).